# Nodejs + Passport + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I m a newbie of Nodejs.

Refer to link.
https://www.danielgynn.com/build-an-authentication-app-using-express-node-passport/

After I login to my profile. 
I need to access&read&write the data with auth level.

Such as Admin, user. After that read and write the data.

please suggest us based on this link coding.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the directory 'routes', generate a new Javascript file. It should have something like:

```
module.exports.findUser = function(req, res, next){
    User.findOne({ 'local.email':  req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if(!user){
            res.status(404).send('User with the e-mail address ' + req.body.email + ' is not found'); 
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(user);
        }
    }
}

module.exports.editUser = function(req, res, next){
    User.update({ 'local.email':  req.body.email }, req.body.newUserObject, function(err) {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send('Something went wrong :('); 
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('User successfully updated :)');
        }
    }
}
```

For the editUser function, you should either

1. Send the entire user object to the function in newUserObject or
2. Use something like: { $set: { keyToUpdate1: valueToUpdate1, keyToUpdate2: valueToUpdate2 } }

If you want to give users roles, like 'Admin', 'SectionAdmin', 'RegularUser', 'Guest' and such, you should keep them in the User Schema like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({  
  local: {
    email: String,
    password: String,
    role: String
  },
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {  
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {  
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

and check user's role in every single step he takes.

Answer (score 0):

The author has provided an github repository example : https://github.com/danielgynn/express-authentication

For the scope authorization , take a look at :

https://github.com/danielgynn/express-authentication/blob/14ca39753f4bd5cc7189786b184b8be36903a102/routes/index.js#L38&L52

an example :

```
router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));
```